# prove $2\sin^4(x)+2\cos^4(x)+\sin^2(2x)=2$

Tags: trigonometry

\begin{align}2\sin^4(x) + 2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) + 2\cos^4(x)&=2(\sin^4(x) + \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) + \cos^4(x))\\
&=2(\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x))^2 -\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\\
&=2(1) -\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) \\
&=2-\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)
\end{align}
And I'm stuck

Comment: since $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, it follows that $\sin^2(2x)=\color{red}4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin^2 2x = (\sin 2x)^2 = (2 \sin x \cos x)^2 = 4 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x,$$ therefore, the LHS is $$2 \sin^4 x + 4 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x + 2 \cos^4 x,$$ which immediately factors as $$2 (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)^2 = 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the formula $\sin (2x)=2\sin x\cos x$ we can expand/reduce
\begin{align}
2\sin^4 x+2\cos^4 x+\sin^2(2x)&=2\sin^4 x + 2\cos^2 x + 4\sin^2 x\cos^2 x\\
&=2(\sin^2 x+\cos^2x)^2\\
&=2(1)^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sin^2 2x = 4\sin^2 x \cos^2 x$$

Let $\sin x = a$ and $\cos x = b$

RHS of your equation becomes:

$$ 2a^4 + 4a^2b^2+2b^4 = 2(a^2+b^2)^2= 2(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)^2 = 2 =RHS$$